# How can I select the closest HTML5 element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

We're integrating analytics into an app, and we're looking to grab the `location` of an element. In this case, there is no good div that gives a location, so we're trying to grab the nearest element.

Is this possible using `.closest`? Can I pass an array of tags `['header', 'article', section]`, and the nearest element that the clicked element is near is selected?

```js
var tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.details'));

function handleTabClick(e) {
  var tabNode = e.target;
  tabLabel = tabNode.innerText;
};

tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', handleTabClick);
});
```

Comment: Please show the HTML in a [mcve] - click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Define nearest.

Comment: Nearrst parent element.

Comment: Nearest _ancestor_? Parent implies a single level of traversal.

Comment: Yes. Nearest ancestor

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate from nearest STATIC html container or from the document

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e) {  
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="SECTION" || tgt.closest("section")....) {
   // handle section
  }
  else if (tgt.tagName==="ARTICLE" || tgt.closest("article")....) {) {
   // handle article
  }
})
```